# iOS SWRevealViewController how to hide the left part programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I included SWRevealViewController objective-c library with my swift project,

it's working fine,

my question is that i want to hide that left menu programtically when the user clicks on an empty space inside its table view.

i didn't know how, could you help please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the left menu programmatically just call the method

```
- (IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender;
```

which is in SWRevealViewController.m class

---

If you want to capture the click on tableView's area where there are no cells, you can follow SunburstEnzo's advice.
Add a UITapUITapGestureRecognizer on the viewDidLoad method of the class with the tableView.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableviewTapped)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]; //really important
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (void) tapped
{
   [self.revealViewController revealToggle:nil];
}
```

Comment: well thank you, but i can't try it because sounds like i don't know how to catch the click on the **space** of the tableview. In other words, my table view has static four cells. and thus there are extra space at the bottom of the table view controller, i want to capture the click on this extra space, could you help please?

Comment: If I were you I would add a UITapGestureRecognizer for the whole of the view when the SWRevealViewController is visible. The tap would call the revealToggle method. It would seem undesirable that someone would want to interact with the tableView while this is visible anyway, right? Correct me if I am wrong. It may help to post a screenshot if possible.

Comment: I edited the answer to reply to your second question

Comment: @metronic where should I copy that code to please? I work on swift, i don't know anything on Objective-C

Comment: You have to put the UITapGestureRecognizer's code on the same class of you tableView, in your viewDidLoad method.